# Please explain the difference with these two queries and what they are doing

Tags: mysql, sql, select

a)

```
 Select HotelID, HotelName, ParkingSpaces, cityID
 from hotels as xyz
 where ParkingSpaces > (Select avg(ParkingSpaces)
                        from Hotels
                        where cityID = xyz.cityID);
```

b)

```
 select HotelName, ParkingSpaces, cityid
 from Hotels
 where ParkingSpaces > (Select avg(ParkingSpaces)
                        from Hotels);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first query correlates between the outer query and the sub query and returns the details of the hotels that have more than the average number of parking spaces in that city.

The second query has no such correlation, and returns the details of the hotels with more than the average number of parking spaces, regardless of the city.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are selecting (slightly different) information about hotels that have more than the average number of parking spaces.

The first is checking the average number of parking spaces of hotels in the same city.  The curious fact is that if there's a city with a single hotel recorded, that hotel will not be listed.  It uses a correlated sub-query, which is why there's the table alias `xyz` (`FROM Hotels AS xyz`) and the join condition in the sub-query using it.

The second is checking the average number of parking spaces of all the hotels known, regardless of city.